# In CFA model, why observed measures operate as dependent variables?

Tags: structural-equation-modeling, confirmatory-factor

I am curious that why in CFA model, observed measures operate as dependent variables.
In my understanding, observed measures served as data point that estimating other parameters, such as latent variables and errors.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're seen as being caused by the latent variables. We hypothesize that you have a certain level of some variable (say, intelligence). The higher your intelligence, the higher the score that you will get on tests of intelligence. So the score on the tests (the measured variables) depend on the level of intelligence (the latent variable).